# How to "ripple" a blend effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm familiar with blend and using the envelope mesh but I can't seem to duplicate an effect like this, other than painstakingly drawing each line individually :P Your help is greatly appreciated! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Wrap Tool** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Start by drawing a line Field dont worry if its uniform then start drawing with Wrap somewhat randomly over it with a very low pressure and low simplify values.

[image]

**Image 1**: Lines.

[image]

**Image 2**: quick demo with a little practice and tighter field you should be able to do whats in your target image.